# XMLHttpRequest.send returns undefined

Tags: javascript

Hi everyone my problem is `upload()` every-time returns `undefined` but i am expecting true or false. Please correct me ! and teach me where i am doing wrong. uploadToS3 is another function which i am calling for upload image on S3.

```
if(upload("fileFieldId","hiddenTextFieldId","docType","uploadId")){
    alert("success");
}
else{
    alert("upload fail");
}

function upload(fileFieldId,hiddenTextFieldId,docType,uploadId){
    document.getElementById(uploadId).innerHTML = "<b>Uploading ...</b>";
    var dt= new Date();
    var file = document.getElementById(fileFieldId).files[0];
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari   Tue, 07 Jun 2016 14:40:00 GMT
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    // alert(file.name);
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "/sellerprofile/uploadajax/");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            var result = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            let headers = {
                'Accept': '*/*',
                'Content-Type': file.type, // or where ever your file object is.
                'Authorization': result.signature, // which you receive from your server
                'x-amz-acl' : 'private', // required
                'x-amz-date' : dt.toUTCString() // required
            }
            let putURL = result.url;
            let nm = result.fileName;
            // alert(result.fileName);
            let uploader = uploadToS3(putURL, headers, file)

            uploader.upload()
            .then((result) => {
                document.getElementById(hiddenTextFieldId).value = nm;
                document.getElementById(uploadId).innerHTML = "<b>File Uploaded</b>";
                document.getElementById(uploadId).style.color = "green";
                document.getElementById(fileFieldId).value = "";
                document.getElementById(fileFieldId).required = false; 
                return true;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                document.getElementById(uploadId).innerHTML = "<b>Uploading failed....</b>";
                document.getElementById(uploadId).style.color = "red";
                return false;
            })
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    var data =  {"type": file.type , "time": dt.toUTCString(), "extention" : (file.name).split('.').pop(),"docType": docType}
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use either callback or promise to make this work. I would prefer callback solution.

```
upload("fileFieldId", "hiddenTextFieldId", "docType", "uploadId", function (status) {
    if (status) {
        alert("success");
    }
    else{
        alert("upload fail");
    }
});
```

Then upload function should support last argument as a callback:

```
function upload(fileFieldId,hiddenTextFieldId,docType,uploadId, callback) {
    ......
        uploader.upload()
        .then((result) => {
            document.getElementById(hiddenTextFieldId).value = nm;
            document.getElementById(uploadId).innerHTML = "<b>File Uploaded</b>";
            document.getElementById(uploadId).style.color = "green";
            document.getElementById(fileFieldId).value = "";
            document.getElementById(fileFieldId).required = false; 
            callback(true);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            document.getElementById(uploadId).innerHTML = "<b>Uploading failed....</b>";
            document.getElementById(uploadId).style.color = "red";
            callback(false);
        })
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making an AJAX request call which is asynchronous and in the default flow, your function would return nothing. Each of your return statements is in the onreadystatechange() method. So if you call your method, it will make the AJAX request and would quit immediately, return 'undefined' as there is no return statement here:

```
var data =  {"type": file.type , "time": dt.toUTCString(), "extention" : (file.name).split('.').pop(),"docType": docType}
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

You may return something like a flag value, to determine if the call was successfully sent to the server, like this:

```
return 'CALL_SENT';
```

And check the value returned like:

```
var valReturned = upload("fileFieldId","hiddenTextFieldId","docType","uploadId");
if(valReturned === 'CALL_SENT'){
    alert("Call sent to the server");
}
else if(valReturned === true){
    alert("succcess");
}
else{
    alert("upload fail");
}
```

Hope this helps.